# Widget Layering in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using the **place** geometry manager to make draggable widgets. I've noticed however, that the last widget made gets priority in layering. In other words it always appears over the widgets made before it. Is there any way to change widget layering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [tk lower](http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tk/lower.n.html) whose [Tkinter](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/universal.html) form is

```
window.lower(belowThis=None)
```